# NPM installing Dependencies from package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies, package.json

Im a bit confused. On my laptop, as I built up my project, my `package.json` got populated with dependencies as I installed them.

It looks like this:

```
"main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.8",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.2",
    "redux": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.3.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "stylelint": "^4.5.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.15",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.7.3"
  },
```

Now, on my new system, pulled the repo & was under the impression that all I have to call is `npm install` & npm would read package.json & download all the dependencies and their specified versions. That didnt happen.

So, my question is, how do we correctly, install all of these dependencies onto a new system.

Would it be a matter of running `npm i --save [all the dependencies]`

& `npm i --save-dev [all the dev dependencies]`

Also, how would the version number be resolved if I do the above? I mean, package.json has the versions specified while running the above two commands would download the latest versions of each package.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to install the latest module versions meet the version requirements, you should use the command:

```
npm i
```

In that case, for `immutable` module, for example, will be installed the latest 3.x version.

But if you want to install **the same** versions as on your first development pc, you need too do the following:

```
npm shrinkwrap # run this command on first pc 
npm i          # run this command on a new pc
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to call is npm install, it will download the most recent major versions (^ caret range syntax) listed in dependencies and devDependencies

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

To install a specific version, remove the caret e.g.

```
"react": "0.14.8",
```

You can use 'npm shrinkwrap' to lock down the versions of a package's dependencies -- cre­ates a file npm-shrinkwrap.json containing the exact pack­age ver­sions in the entire hier­ar­chy

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap

---

package.json interactive guide http://browsenpm.org/package.json